# How could I get the abstract state and the discrete state?

Tags: drake

I notice that the compass_gait has a discrete state for the position of the stance toe along the ramp and a Boolean indicator for “left support” (true when the stance leg is the left leg) in https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.examples.compass_gait.html.
My question is, how could I get the discrete state and the abstract  state?